# Why does my database get reset after each deployment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to deploying to aws as well as flask. Basically I have a simple Flask app but every time I make a change and deploy the new code to aws elastic beanstalk, the db gets reset.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

application = app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'hello'

.
.
.


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    weight = db.Column(db.Float)
    workouts = db.relationship('Workout', backref='user', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'weight')

user_schema = UserSchema(strict=True)
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True, strict=True)
.
.
.


db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect that each time I
`eb deploy flask-env` my db wouldnt get reset but it does. For instance if i create a user and then later change something in the code and deploy, that user is gone.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `db.create_all()` for the new deployments?

Comment: Is your sqlite db being created on a persistent disk? Sounds like EB is creating a new instance each deploy, which means your old container is trashed and a new one created. You need to either put the db file on a mounted block storage disk or use a hosted db product.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Create an EBS Volume
2. Load the database into that volume
3. Attach the EBS Volume to your Beanstalk app with an .ebextension.  An example can be [found here](http://www.janblaha.net/blog/attach-existing-ebs-volume-to-elastic-beanstalk).

With all that being said, this is not a highly available, well architected solution and will deteriorate at scale rapidly.

You will want to replace SQLite with an RDS instance at some point in the future before it becomes a problem.